# Problems with double & Java.lang.String -Text Fields

Tags: java, netbeans, double

This is a kind of a newb question but I'm really new to programming and I'm only a little over a week into a programming course in grade 11. We use Java, and work with Netbeans.

What I'm working on right now is this:

> During a special sale at a store, a 10% discount is taken off of
>   purchases over $10.00.
>
> Create an application that prompts the user for the amount of
>   purchases and then returns the discounted price, as well as the
>   discount amount itself.

My Code:

```
 DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat ("$###.00");
 double purchases, discount, finalPrice;
 purchases = Double.parseDouble (purchaseInput.getText ());
 if (purchases >= 10) {
     discount = purchases * 0.10;
 }    
 else { 
     discount = 0;
 }
 finalPrice = purchases - discount;
 discountOutput.setText (discount);
 finalPriceOutput.setText (finalPrice);
```

The problem is the last two lines. I'm trying to set the values to text fields. It says that it is finding double, but needs `java.lang.String`. I tried changing them to a string with `double.toString ()` but it says the double can't be dereferenced. I'm pretty confused right now, please help.

I'm sure the fix isn't very complicated, but I've looked every content section we have learned so far twice and still cant find how to fix my problem.

Comment: Welcome at SO. I added the 'homework' tag to indicate that this is homework. For the future please keep this in mind.

Comment: Please indent your code for better readability in the future. Also, avoid uppercase for attributes, parameters and variables - it is only a convention, but very helpful when reading foreign code. Uppercase is limited for class names, and therefore constructors. Have a look at the Markdown-editing-help, to be found at every major edit box in the upper right corner. Feel welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a `DecimalFormat` to convert doubles to strings. So try this:

```
 DiscountOutput.setText(x.format(Discount));
 FinalPriceOutput.setText(x.format(FinalPrice));
```

You can also do it without using `DecimalFormat`, but the result will be slightly different because the numbers are not formatted as "$###.00":

```
 DiscountOutput.setText(Discount.toString());
 FinalPriceOutput.setText(FinalPrice.toString());
```

Also, as a suggestion, I think money quantities look better when you use "`$#,##0.00`". That way you have thousands separator (,) and fractions of a dollar show up like $0.51 instead of $.51, which looks weird. So do:

```
 DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat ("$#,##0.00");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't think we ever learned that the decimal format converted double to strings, so thas useful to know. This fixed my problem perfectly. Thanks for your help and for not laughing at the newbie question.

Answer (score 2):

Write this:

```
DiscountOutput.setText(Double.toString(Discount));
FinalPriceOutput.setText(Double.toString(FinalPrice));
```

Also, remember that in Java all variables should start with a lower case character. The standard way to declare your variables should be:

```
double purchases, discount, finalPrice;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also didn't remember variables were supposed to start with a lower case character, thank you.

Comment: @IceMage88 You're welcome :) If this answer was helpful for you in any way, please consider an upvote

Answer (score 1):

TextField's setText method always accepts only String. So, you need to do String.valueOf()

```
DiscountOutput.setText(String.valueOf(Discount));
FinalPriceOutput.setText(String.valueOf(FinalPrice));
```

Comment: I chose someone else's answer, but yours still helped me as I did not know this was the proper way to format this, thank you.